# Получить версию objective-c библиотеки

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

Есть некоторый SDK, в нем хочется знать текущую версию этого же SDK, но

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

возвращает версию iOS приложения, в которое этот SDK встроен (что логично). Знает ли кто-нибудь как в рантайме достать версию именно SDK?

Comment: Вам точно надо получить эти данные именно через код? Для чего такое понадобилось? Обычно сторонние библиотеки ставятся через менеджеры зависимостей, типа CocoaPods, в нем же версию пода можно узнать одной консольной командой.

Comment: @Olter да, я наверное не совсем ясно выразился - 
я разрабатываю этот sdk. он для аналитики и я хочу в рантайме, в каждом вызове, получать версию "самого себя" и отправлять данные. но получается доставать только лишь версию проекта, в который "я" интегрирован.

Comment: Так, а как SDK к проекту подключаете? Я предполагаю, что это отдельный Cocoa Touch Framework, который вы загрузили куда-то на гитхаб и оформили как под файл, а потом добавляете его в основной проект уже через cocoapods. Или вы напрямую фреймворк в проект кидаете? В любом случае, по идее, вы можете в самом фреймворке создать публичный метод getFrameworkVersion и вызвать его из проекта, должен вернуть правильную версию.

Comment: да, верно, это фреймворк который добавляется через cocoapods.
я тут обнаружил хедер который сам создался и в нем есть

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double my_sdkVersionNumber;

FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char my_VersionString[];

и это работает :) 
поулчается, что вопрос снят, спасибо)

Comment: @KirillGudkov , перенесите комментарий с решением как правильный ответ, возможно еще кому-то эта информация будет полезна и решение будет легче увидеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тут обнаружил хедер который сам создался и в нем есть

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT double my_sdkVersionNumber; 
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char my_VersionString[];`

и это работает :)